# Using ng-attr-href from angular to direct user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So what I am trying to do is for an icon (link), the user will have already logged on and there is a property identified that is true or false. Based on whether that property is true or false, when the user clicks that icon (link), it will take them to one of 2 pages. So looking at different directives within angular, thought I could use ng-switch, but that doesn't seem viable so I thought ng-attr-href could do it. Trying something like (this is pseudo code):

```
<a href="somepage.html" ng-attr-href="object.value: false | goto: "otherpage.html""><span></span></a>
```

So this is like an if/else where when user clicks icon and that value true, they go one place, but if false, they go elsewhere. My difficulty is structuring that and how/where the else goes.

Is there a better way to do this than I am thinking based on what I shared?

Thanks much.

Adding to, where could this be wrong?:

```
                    <a ng-href="{{ ppt.Globals.value == 'false' '#/claimEnter' : '#/clearSwipe' }}">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/submiticon.svg" >
                        <p>Submit a Claim for Reimbursement</p>
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use a ternary within  a `{{}}` expression in `ng-href`

```
<a ng-href="{{object.value ? 'somepage.html' : 'otherpage.html'}}">
```

Comment: Is the "?" mean to be the property? so object.value == 'false' ? 'somepage.html' : ..... ?

Comment: Added some additional detail hoping to get further input.

Answer (score 0):

Put a function inside your controller to provide the value, then call it inside the ng-href. This type of decision of which link to go is the controller's responsibility.

```
ng-href="whereToGo(object.value)"
```

Comment: value is the property in this case. so is {{ object.property }} . That said, I understand the controller's responsibility. Just not sure I am understanding the syntax within the view as labeled. Meaning, so you saying that {{ function in controller ? whereToGo : another whereToGo }}. Do you see where I am lost?

Comment: I dont see why you are struggling with this... but the ternary operator could be used... but in this case I would go with the ng-click instead of ng-href

Comment: I am trying to understand what the '?' operator in there is supposed to do within the tenary. Guess it is trying to provide an 'if'. How would the ng-click go into this with an 'if'?

Comment: The ? operator works as an if... object.value ? "url1" : "url2"