# How to use expression in ng-href for passing query parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-href

```
<a ng-href="{{a==3 ? 'www.google.com/correct?{{a}}' : 
'www.google.com/correct?{{a+1}}'}}"
```

It throws error.

Error: $parse:lexerr
Lexer Error

Can anyone help please. I am new to angularjs and learning, not able to figure out how should I proceed.

Comment: This syntax is invalid. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @briosheje If the condition is satisfied it should redirect to link1 else to link2.

Comment: @briosheje Please check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595829/using-ng-attr-href-from-angular-to-direct-user-interaction

But I want to pass query parameters in the url.

Comment: use `ng-href="a===3 ? ('www.google.com/correct?' + a) : 
('www.google.com/correct?' + (a+1))"`

Comment: Thank you so much @briosheje. It worked perfectly. :)

Comment: I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use:

```
ng-href="a===3 ? ('www.google.com/correct?' + a) : ('www.google.com/correct?' + (a+1))"
```

Since it's an ng-tag, you shouldn't use brackets, and treat it like regular javascript.